# SmartcardReader, which driver(-file) is really used?

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, card-reader, pcscd

I have a problem with my SmartCard-Reader (**Cherry ST1044-U**) in my Kubuntu 14.10 (64bit).
It does not fully work (when trying **to sign** data, error is thrown).
(i read about the "default" driver, which comes along with ubuntu, has problems with my reader and extended APDUs)

Same reader works pretty fine with Windows!

So i downloaded the Linux driver from the Cherry-Website.
(http://www.cherry.de/files/software/ifdokccid_lnx_x64-3.5.1.tar.gz)
(in the drivers readme is to read: SUPPORTS EXTENDED APDUs! (this is what i need!))

[image]

But after trying to install the driver, i am a little confused.
I notice the same problems...

The driver-package does only contain one "binary" file (**ifdokccid.so**) and a few scripts in different folders.
Questions is:
How can i find out if the "driver"-file (ifdokccid.so) is really used?

**EDIT:**

1. i changed the install-scripts **dropdir** to /usr/lib/pcsc/drivers (it was wrong)
2. i unpluged the reader, re-installed the 64bit driver and rebooted the system.
3. then i `tail -f /var/log/syslog`
4. plugin again the reader and see the output:

`Dec 12 12:18:41 Kub-Ben kernel: [  121.798776] usb 4-2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ohci-pci
Dec 12 12:18:41 Kub-Ben kernel: [  121.974158] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=046a, idProduct=002d
Dec 12 12:18:41 Kub-Ben kernel: [  121.974167] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Dec 12 12:18:41 Kub-Ben kernel: [  121.974172] usb 4-2: Product: SmartTerminal XX44
Dec 12 12:18:41 Kub-Ben kernel: [  121.974177] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: Cherry GmbH
Dec 12 12:18:41 Kub-Ben mtp-probe: checking bus 4, device 3: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb4/4-2"
Dec 12 12:18:41 Kub-Ben mtp-probe: bus: 4, device: 3 was not an MTP device
Dec 12 12:18:43 Kub-Ben pcscd: readerfactory.c:1020:RFInitializeReader() Open Port 0x200000 Failed (usb:046a/002d:libudev:0:/dev/bus/usb/004/003)
Dec 12 12:18:43 Kub-Ben pcscd: readerfactory.c:312:RFAddReader() Cherry SmartTerminal XX44 init failed.
Dec 12 12:18:43 Kub-Ben pcscd: hotplug_libudev.c:391:HPAddDevice() Failed adding USB device: Cherry SmartTerminal XX44`

Then, i did following:

[image]
(which shows the same...)

**Edit 2:**
i read the link provided by Frantique:  [forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/kartenleser-von-cherry-verwenden](http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/kartenleser-von-cherry-verwenden)
and tried to install all packages which are declared there.
All packages were already installed on my maschine, **except**: libtowitoko2 and pcsc-omnikey
i could install libtowitoko2 but i could't install pcsc-omnikey.
pcsc-omnikey **was not found** by `sudo apt-get install pcsc-omnikey`

this is the new result (with missing pcsc-omnikey package):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer to my own question!
After trying to find out why it doesn't work, i found following info on Cherry-International-Website (not DE site):

[image]

So, i went to OmniKey-Website and downloaded the driver for
**OmniKey CardMan 3121**.
http://www.hidglobal.com/drivers/21278
After installing it, it works like a charm!

(**Frantique** pointed similar out in his comments, **thanks for that**!)

@Frantique:
`lsmod | grep ifdokccid` still does not show anything, even now when reader works!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the module is loaded with:

```
lsmod | grep ifdokccid
```

If not, you can load it manually with `modprobe` command.

Comment: Thanks, when i enter your command, i get "nothing". When trying to load the module manual, following is shown: **modprobe: FATAL: Module ifdokccid not found.**

Comment: Could you provide the messages during install? Also, please specify if your system is 32 or 64bits.

Comment: it's 64bit. i edited my Question. Result after calling: sudo ./install.sh: `Installing OMNIKEY CardMan CCID Smartcard reader driver ...

Copying ifdokccid_lnx_x64-3.5.1.bundle to /usr/local/pcsc/drivers/ ...

Installation finished!
`

Comment: Reboot your computer, than watch the output of `dmesg` when plugging in the card reader. You should see activity on it. If not, it means that `pcscd` is not installed or is not active.

Comment: On 32bit I needed  `libc6 libusb-1.0-0 libpcsc-perl`  packages. Search for them on the 64bit.

Comment: i edited my question to add more infos (comment section here is too small). Please take a look at it.

Comment: On a german forum it says that you need the following packages: `pcsc-tools, pcsc-omnikey, pcscd, libpcsc-perl, libtowitoko2` (source: http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/kartenleser-von-cherry-verwenden/)

Comment: Thanks for your help, i edited again my Question (Edit 2)

Comment: I've found this as well: http://askubuntu.com/questions/284440/why-id-card-reader-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-12-04-12-10-using-omnikey3121